# Animations stopped working

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I know it sounds a bit general, but this is exactly the issue. After roaming a bit in my app, something I do (don't know what) causes the app to lose all its animations.

Animations like: keyboard popping up/down, view controllers push animations... Or even my coded animations. Nothing works. Everything just pops in/out instantly.

I'm not even sure which code of mine causes this...

Could it be a bug in my code? or a bug in my device? or a bug in iOS8?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Animations will stop working when performing them in a background queue. Ideally, you would find and fix such instances in your code. Here is a library that helps track them down:

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTFoundation/blob/develop/Core/Source/iOS/Debug/UIView%2BDTDebug.m

This is a good workaround (from the App developer forums) to get animations to work again:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]
```

Comment: You answer helped me indirectly: to stop a UIButton animation, I was calling `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` without immediately realizing that I wasn't stopping the animations for an instance, but for every UIView in my app.

Answer (score 0):

OK... Found it.

I was loading a new view controller. In the viewDidLoad I have put a block to see if the app has permissions to create a reminder. The loading of the page was postponed after the completion of the block and that's what caused the bug.

This is my BAD code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.shouldAlert = YES;

    [[EventStoreManager sharedManager] connectRemindersPermissionWithCompletion:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            [self initData];
            [self initGraphics];
            [self pageLoaded];
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\"APP_NAME\" Would Like to Access Your Reminders" message:@"Settings -> Privacy -> Reminders" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                    [self closeAddTaskButtonPressed:nil];
                }];

            });
        }
    }];
}
```

This is my correction:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.shouldAlert = YES;
    [self initData];
    [self initGraphics];
    [self pageLoaded];

    [[EventStoreManager sharedManager] connectRemindersPermissionWithCompletion:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\"APP_NAME\" Would Like to Access Your Reminders" message:@"Settings -> Privacy -> Reminders" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                    [self closeAddTaskButtonPressed:nil];
                }];

            });
        }
    }];
}
```

Bug solved... :)

Answer (score -1):

Unlikely but: try searching for "speed" in your code base.  In case you

> [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.layer.speed = 99.0;

or something similar.

Comment: It is Not a Answer of Her Question